# Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: wcf, web-services, dispose, wcf-client

I am writing a tool to integrate with a web service, I have a method which just builds an ImportExportSoapClient object which is used to call the API methods for the web service, but when I call one of the methods I am getting Cannot access a disposed object System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel? anyone had a similar experience or could lend a hand?

Comment: please, provide code example of how you creating and using client

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be trying to use an already-closed `CommunicationObject` (like a `ChannelFactory`). When the object is in a `Closed` or `Closing` state, you get an `ObjectDisposedException`.

MSDN Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms405496.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and it was because my client was trying to re-use an old connection that was hanging around from the previous time the client was run.  The problem went away when I re-tried a minute or so later,